# Сохранения файлов с разными названиями

Tags: python

Извините за глупый вопрос, но как сделать так, чтобы если есть уже файл с именем screenshot.png программа создавала файл screenshot001.png и так до бесконечности?

```py
import keyboard
import pyautogui
from pymsgbox import *

def foo():
    screen = pyautogui.screenshot('screenshot.png')
    print(screen)
    alert(text='Скриншот сделан', title='Уведомление', button='OK')
keyboard.add_hotkey('-', foo)
keyboard.wait('Ctrl + Q')
```

Comment: тебе надо прочитать диск и есть там есть файл ```screenshot.png``` то делать файл ```screenshot001.png``` и так до бесконечности. Т.е. тебе надо придумать алгоритм перебора файлов в папке и в зависимости от количества файлов, задавать новое имя

Comment: план б. добавлять к названию дату и время а не номер datetime.now()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы узнать есть ли файл на ПК можно сделать так: `os.path.exists(file_path)`
Чтобы сделать бесконечную нумерацию можно сделать так:

```
def foo():
    i = 1
    while True:
        if os.path.exists(f'screenshot{i}.png'):
            i += 1
            continue
        screen = pyautogui.screenshot('screenshot.png')
        print(screen)
        alert(text='Скриншот сделан', title='Уведомление', button='OK')
```

Но так файлы будут не `screenshot001.png`, `screenshot002.png`, ... А будут `screenshot1.png`, `screenshot2.png`, .... Да и к тому же это довольно долго, потому что после каждого скришота будет проверятся всё больше файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui
from pymsgbox import *

count = 0

def foo():
    count += 1
    screen = pyautogui.screenshot('screenshot{str(count).ljust('0')}.png')
    print(screen)
    alert(text='Скриншот сделан', title='Уведомление', button='OK')
keyboard.add_hotkey('-', foo)
keyboard.wait('Ctrl + Q')
```

Comment: при перезапуске программы скришоты начнут затираться